# How to get a row from database using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

i am trying to get a row of data from database using ajax in codeigniter.

Here is the javascript function-

```
$(function(){
    $("button[name='program_view_details']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var program_id=$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>program_management/get_program_data",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",

        data: "program_id="+program_id,
        success: function(row)
        {
            alert(row.program_name);
        }
    });


});
```

I am not sure if the datatype and post is correct or not.

Here is my controller function-

```
public function get_program_data( ){
    $program_id = $this->input->post('program_id');
    $this->load->model('program_management_model');
    $data['programs']= $this->program_management_model->get_program_specific($program_id);
    echo $data;

}
```

Here is the model-

```
function get_program_specific($program_id){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM programs WHERE program_id='".$program_id."'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

I am searching the way of returning the row from controller to javascript. But the alert() is showing "undefined" in the success. Please anyone tell me the whole way through. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just write data: program_id, do not contact the string to it. I guess program_id is the parameter you are sending to controller?

Comment: sorry no luck... it doesn't differ the output...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in model

```
function get_program_specific($program_id){
    $temp=array();
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM programs WHERE program_id='".$program_id."'");
    $temp= $query->row_array();
    echo $temp['program_name'];
}
```

in controller change the line

```
$data['programs']= $this->program_management_model->get_program_specific($program_id);
```

with

```
$this->program_management_model->get_program_specific($program_id);
```

and finally in javascript

```
alert(row);
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

$data['programs']= $this->program_management_model->get_program_specific($program_id);

The $data which you are echoing in the controller is basically an array[]  and programs is an array which is present in $data. Either echo the $data in controller using the

```
      foreach(){}
```

or echo the $query array in your model. That will do the trick.And in ajax success call just append the data to the element in which you want to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

Change names as per your page.

in your script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>managealerts_edit/editalerts',
    type: "POST",
    data: {'id': edit_id},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(row){ 
        //alert(row.sub);
        $('#edit').show();
        $('#sub').val(row.sub);
        $('#mess').val(row.mess);
    }
});
```

in your model:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT fld_id, fld_course_id,fld_sub,fld_mess from tbl_alerts where fld_id='".$det."' ");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $row = $query->row_array(); 
    $data=array("sub" => $row['fld_sub'], "mess" => $row['fld_mess']);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

in your controller:

```
$det = $this->input->post('id');
//$alertsres['tbl_alerts'] = $this->managealerts_m->select_editalerts($det);
$this->managealerts_m->select_editalerts($det);`
```