# Codeigniter ajax - retrieving rows in Codeigniter with JQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm investigating how to retrieve rows from database using Codeigniter and AJAX but it is not working, I followed the steps from here: [How to get a row from database using ajax in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802531/how-to-get-a-row-from-database-using-ajax-in-codeigniter) and nothing:
here is what my code looks like:

table (user):

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_user        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| information    | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

controller (welcome.php):

```
function get_invoices()
    {

        $company = $_POST['pass'];

        $this->login_select->get_login($company);//model

    }
```

view(JQuery) once is loaded there is a form with one type text(named pass) and the other a submit:

```
function sendData(){

        var data = $('form').serialize();
        $('form').unbind('submit'); 

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/welcome/get_invoices',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  $('div#message').html(data);
            }
        });  
    }
```

the model (login_select.php) here is the problem:

```
public function get_login($myid)
    {           
        $temp = array();
        $this->db->select("user.*");
        $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('id_user'=>$myid));
        $temp= $query->row_array();
        echo $temp['name'];
        //return $temp;
    }
```

and finally I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: name

Filename: models/login_select.php

Line Number: 41
```

How to resolve this?, because I'm going to need to recover not just a row but the whole row from a table. Thanks

Comment: Also `$this->db->select("user.*");` is not necessary. **`get_where()`** selects all fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, but I don't know if it's a good practice:

basically I create another view (everything printed here will be updated in my div via ajax):

controller:

```
function get_invoices()
    {

        $data['login2'] = $this->login_select->get_login($company);
        $this->load->view('ajaxtest', $data);///the trick

    }
```

JQuery in the view is the same.

the model (nothing weird here):

```
public function get_login($myid)
    {


        $query = $this->db->get_where('user', array('id_user'=>$myid));

        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

and the trick is create another view in this case ajaxtest.php:

```
<?php


echo sizeof($login2) . " ";

foreach ($login2 as $login2_item):

    echo $login2_item["name"];

endforeach;

?>
```

If anyone needs this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

in login_select.php, `$temp` may not equal what you think it does.

`$temp['name']` doesnt exist and you're trying to use it so it throws an undefined index error. Make sure that `$temp['name']` exists before using it via something like

```
return isset($temp['name']) ? $temp['name'] : false;
```

Or run `die(var_dump($temp))` there to see whats going on.

Comment: But I need the value(s) of 'name' from table, how Do I get that value in variable?

Comment: I got: array(0) { }  why?

Comment: Because your sql query is malformed somehow. I am not familiar enough with codeigniter anymore to help any further. You should check out a tutorial on how to pull items from a db with CI.